# i got this errors on service restart apache2 how can i solve it

Tags: server, apache2, php

[error image in my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVvdQ.png)

I tried to uninstall and install apache2 but I got the same error

Comment: Please avoid sending images of errors. Better use copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You got a syntax error on /etc/apache2/mods, try purging apache2
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2, then install again sudo apt-get install apache2 -y